# In a bar chart i need an Average bar to compare it will top 5 Bars that i have in graph in spotfire

Tags: spotfire, tibco

I need to plot a bar chart in spotfire where in there should be 6 bars.. 5 bars should be the top 5 values from column and 6th should be the average one that is needed for comparison. for eg. we have cities and the amount spent like this 
new york 200
texas 150
LA 300
windsor 100
New jersey 250
Bay ridge 120

so out of this it should have top  5 and 6th bar for average which will be 200+150+300+100+250+120/6.

can anyone please suggest solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is backwards from info-graphic logic and would be confusing to everyone other than people with specific knowledge of this design and that's why it isn't a feature of Spotfire. Instead, insert a line showing the average.

```
Right Click on your Chart > Properties > Lines & Curves
```

Then either click on the `Horizontal Line: Avg(Y)` or add your own

Comment: bu that will avg of top five not for the whole column. I need an average comparison for whole column. for eg if we have 30 columns and total is 3000 then 3000/30.

Comment: You can use a script to populate an annotation but what you are trying to do defeats the info graphic. What you could do is pivot your data to have 6 columns with your desired results and place this on the X AXIS. I can't think of another way natively.